# how to output for one of loop in the nested loop in shell script

Tags: shell, tcsh

I need the list of files form 6 directories and save them in different files. My code is

```
cd /eos/uscms/
foreach f (store/user/lnujj/ramkrishna/GENSIM/*150k)
        foreach d ($f/*/*/*/*/*) 
               echo "'/$d'," 
        end
end
cd -
```

That only list the files But, How can I save the output for each first for loop in different files.

Comment: Which shell are you using ?

Comment: Can't you just change that echo into something like `echo "'/$d'," >> $(basename $f).txt` or so. An example of the expected result would help.

Comment: @mofoe I tried this but it is not working.

Comment: What dose "it is not working" mean? What is the problem?

Comment: @mofoe: Error is "Illegal variable name."

Comment: (dang back-ticks. trying again) : `[t]csh` doesn't support the `$(cmd)` form of cmd-substitution. Try mofoe idea, but with echo "'/$d'," >> \`basename $f  \`.txt ... etc. Good luck. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a version of your script that works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh
set count=0 # initialise count

cd /eos/uscms/
foreach f (store/user/lnujj/ramkrishna/GENSIM/*150k)
    foreach d ($f/*/*/*/*/*) 
           echo "'/$d'," >> dir_$count.txt` # or what ever... >> `basename $f.txt`
    end
    @ count++ #increment count
end
cd -
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: When I tried this I got Error saying : dir_0.txt: Operation not permitted.

Comment: Thanks. Now its working. The directory in which I was saving is not writable thats why I got above error.

Comment: Cool. You might want to mark this question as answered then.